# In the theory of computation, why are regular expressions (ab)* and a*b* not equal?

Tags: regex

What is the language expressed by these expressions and why aren't they equal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`L1 = (ab)*` stands for `ab` repeated 0 or more times.
`L2 = a*b*` stands for `a` repeated 0 or more times followed by `b` repeated 0 or more times.

Those languages aren't equal because word `abab` is in language `L1` but it's not in language `L2`.
Those languages aren't equal because word `a` is in language `L2` but it's not in language `L1`.

There is a very useful service [web service](https://regex101.com/) used for comparing regular expressions. Once you type in the regular expression, it describes it and let's you test it.

Examples of words in those languages:

L1:

- ""
- "ab"
- "abab"
- "ababab"

L2:

- ""
- "a"
- "aa"
- "bbbb"
- "ab"
- "aaaabbbbbbb"

Comment: @SoumyaPawar no. The other is just `a`s followed by `b`s.

Comment: (ab)*={€,ab,abab,....}
a*b*={€,a,aa,bb,ab, abab, ...} 
aren't the strings accepted by both languages same? Won't abab,ababab be accepted by a*b* too? If not, why?
Thanks

Comment: @SoumyaPawar look how I described those languages and look at the examples

Comment: @SoumyaPawar look, single letter `a` is a word in `L2` and isn't a word in `L1`.